# Who created Litecoin?

Tags: litecoin

I've been reading about Litecoin, yet I haven't found any mention to a person or group responsible for the fork. Who created litecoin and did he write a whitepaper explaining why?

Edit:

After some searching it appears to be Charles Lee. Yet no whitepaper yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [original announcement post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=47417.0) by [coblee](https://github.com/coblee/). In a short bit of research, I wasn't able to find a formal paper. The post describes the changes divergent from Bitcoin.